# Use ArcGIS for Server geocoding service results with PyQGIS

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, arcgis-server, geocoding

An ArcGIS for Server geocoding service can be used via http get (singleline geocoding for 'Jugendamt' [youth office]) http://secure.erlangen.de/arcgiser/rest/services/Comp_fromModel/GeocodeServer/findAddressCandidates?Address=&Postal=&City=&Region=&Country=&SingleLine=Jugendamt&category=&outFields=&maxLocations=&outSR=&searchExtent=&location=&distance=&magicKey=&f=html

and returns some results (below, Address Candidates):

[image]

**Question**: Is it possible to extract the resulting coordinates for further use, e.g. in PyQGIS?

Comment: Have you tried using `...&f=json` instead of HTML?

Comment: Here is an &f-=json example response http://sampleserver3.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/Hydrography/Watershed173811/FeatureServer/0/query?where=objectid+%3D+objectid&outfields=*&f=json that or geocoding (magic key) http://geocode.arcgis.com/arcgis/rest/services/World/GeocodeServer/suggest?text=trea&location=-115.172783,36.114789&distance=20000&f=pjsonshould be easy to extract out using python

Comment: outch... must have been blind... Along with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12965203/how-to-get-json-from-webpage-into-python-script this solves my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The comments above (using f=json instead of f=html, thanks all) along with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12965203/how-to-get-json-from-webpage-into-python-script solved this question. Intented is a QGIS Plugin, which makes use of such geocoding service results.